# On different errors set different view files in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework3, custom-exceptions, view-templates

I have dispatch error listener and there I get thrown exception and check if it is instance of CustomeException. In that case I want to set custom view template with default layout.

```
public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events, $priority = 1)
{
    $this->listeners[] = $events->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, [$this, 'handleError'], 0);
}

public function handleError(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $request = $e->getParam('application')->getRequest();

    if ($request instanceof ConsoleRequest) {
        return;
    }

    $exception = $e->getResult()->exception;
    if ($exception instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        $view = new ViewModel(['message' => $exception->getMessage()]);
        $view->setTerminal(false);
        $view->setTemplate('admin/filenotfound');
        $e->setViewModel($view);
    }
}
```

For this code I got white page with 'message', but layout is not set. 
How to add custom view template on default layout for module?